# How do I use a variable reference inside another variable?

Tags: c, variables

I want to do something like so:

```
int num1,num2,num3;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
     printf("%i",num {put i+1 here});
}
```

Do not tell me a way to get around this, as this is not actually my code.

Tell me a way to use variable references inside variable names please.

Comment: You need to use an array num[3], you can't change variable names like that.

Comment: *Do not tell me a way to get around this* says it all... please go read up on C Programming instead of marching on here asking how to do it, it reeks of laziness and ignorance on your part.

Answer (score 1):

> Tell me a way to use variable references inside variable names please.

That is not possible. You need an array.

The simple (and best) way is simply:

```
int num[3] = {0};
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
     printf("%i", num[i]);
}
```

However, if you for some reason **can't** change the name of the 3 num variables (aka num1, num2, num3), you can create an array with pointers to the 3 variables:

```
int num1=0, num2=0, num3=0;
int* pNum[3] = {&num1, &num2, &num3};  // Create array of pointers to the variables
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
     printf("%i", *pNum[i]);  // Access num1, num2, num3 via the pointer array
}
```

That solution is however not good as it makes the code hard to read and understand.